# Error importing my CSV (1000+ products) with magento 1.9

Tags: magento, csv, importerror, magento-1.9

Anybody got an explanation as to why this is happening.... Im trying to import my products from a CSV file. but even though it states the import was successful it doesn't actually import anything

I go to import my products (CSV) System > Import/Export > Import

upload my csv and get

**Import successfully done.**

BUT! it doesnt actually import ANY products......

The CSV from my DropBox Account.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/n8adpsz7be9hhma/products.csv?dl=0

Comment: Did u use Default Magento DataFlow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also face the same problem, Its issues for `CHARACTER SET` of your database. You can only import `utf8` CHARECTER SET, but right now your `product.csv` file is `character set ASCII`. The `ASCII` character is not supports, and magento does not check character set of the csv file.

So, Final solution is need to change character set  of your `csv` file.

1. Open the `product.csv` in simple text editor(note++, notepad etc)
2. `Save as` a new file with `charecter set utf-8`.
3. Import `product.csv`.

I hope that my help may be help for you.

Comment: Hi i have done this but its not importing all the products just 17, i have a new csv that is unicode UTF-8 and its imported 17 of 335

i saved in utf-8 with notepad and its now saying 

Can not find required columns: sku

Comment: You mast misplaced attributes in your `csv`  file. check manually & correct it.  I hope that your problem will be resolved.

Comment: @Supravat I have the same issues imported 458 products but just 20 are showing in the backend and database. all the others are not imported